# Para que serve e quando usar versão em arquivos .js e .css?

Tags: javascript, css

Para que serve e quando usar

arquivo.js?v=123(exemplo)

arquivo.css?v=123(exemplo)

Quais benefícios e como o navegador interpreta isso

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Isso é feito para evitar que o navegador use uma versão em cache do arquivo. Se o seu site chama o mesmo JS ou CSS em várias páginas, o browser baixa esses arquivos do servidor somente uma vez, e quando precisar deles novamente, pega do cache. Mas se você altera o arquivo no servidor, o browser não fica sabendo disso, e continua usando a versão antiga.

Ao passar qualquer parâmetro no final do arquivo, você altera a URL, e o browser passa a considerar que se trata de um arquivo diferente. Assim, baixa o novo arquivo, e faz cache dele. Para forçar que o browser *nunca* faça cache, geralmente usa-se um *timestamp* como parâmetro. Isso é útil durante o desenvolvimento de um site. Se você sempre passar o timestamp atual em um site em produção, você anula totalmente o cache do browser, e o carregamento do site vai ficar um pouco mais lento, já que o cache não será utilizado mesmo quando poderia ser.

Answer (score 6):

Normalmente isto é feito, utilizando alguma linguagem back-end de apoio, para estar modificando o parâmetro timestamp no final do arquivo, por exemplo:

```
<link href="css/application.css?1305608333" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.1.11.min.js?1305599721" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Forçando o navegador a carregar sempre a última versão do arquivo, evitando problemas de cache.

Comment: Isso não torna mais lento o carregamento?

Comment: Que eu saiba, não influência na performance, e evita que o cliente veja alterações antigas, por estar sempre carregando a última versão do arquivo.