# Como forçar carregamento de arquivos JS e CSS a cada nova versão publicada?

Tags: javascript, css, cache

Toda a vez que publico uma nova versão da minha aplicação web (um sistema multiempresas) que possua alterações em arquivos JS e CSS, alguns clientes reclamam de erros e acabo constatando que é a *cache* do navegador e tenho que instruir o cliente a atualizar a página com <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd>.

Gostaria de saber se há uma forma de eu forçar o navegador a buscar os arquivos JS e CSS no servidor toda a vez que eu publicar uma nova versão (talvez salvando um *cookie* no cliente informando a versão do sistema na última vez que foi acessado e comparar a cada carregamento).

Procurei no Google e não encontrei nenhuma informação que realmente me ajudasse. Minha aplicação é em C#.Net.

Comment: Relacionada: [Para que serve e quando usar versão em arquivos .js ou .css?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41153/4808)

Comment: talvez vc encontre algo que possa usar aqui: https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/

Comment: Não sei como fazer isso no IIS, mas em algum lugar do seu app.config você pode instruir os navegadores a não fazer cache desses arquivos.

Comment: Se for pra gerar um link dinâmico acho que concatenar o timestamp como parâmetro na url também funciona, como em requisições ajax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Concatene algum número aleatório que varie a cada carregamento, no final da extensão do arquivo.

EX: estilo.css?v=1651516151;

Answer (score 7):

Em PHP usando o timestamp do arquivo você sabe se ele sofreu alguma alteração, forçando um novo carregamento, caso não ele não seja alterado continua pega o que já está no cache do navegador.

Com php faça assim, mas pode usar a mesmo ideia para sua linguagem.

exemplo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=<?php echo filemtime('css/style.css'); ?>">
```

No navegador vai aparecer assim:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/estilo.css?v=1429015974" />
```

Em JS seria usando uma função para gerar um numero (data > timestamp) a ser adicionado no final do arquivo.

Exemplo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function addcss(css){
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getTime();
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var s = document.createElement('link');
        s.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
        s.setAttribute('href', css+'?v='+n)
        head.appendChild(s);
    }   

    //chame a função passando o caminho do CSS ou JS 
    addcss('css/style.css');
</script>
```

A saida será:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=1457636631802">
```

Comment: Da uma olha nessa outra forma apenas com JS

Comment: Obg Marcelo Diniz, começando hoje aqui por aqui.

Comment: a comunidade que agradece por vc estar ajudando

Comment: Pow isso me ajudaou muito, obrigado!!!!

Answer (score -4):

**Como eu trabalho com Wordpress eu faço dessa forma, sem a necessidade de criar um .JS:**

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>?v=<?php echo time(); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

**A saída é assim:**

```
<link href="https://www.o_site_com_br/wp-content/themes/tema_2020/style.css?v=1594856278" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Dê mais detalhes sobre o código e menos sobre você :)

Comment: Toda vez que acessar a página o sistema vai carregar de novo, desconsiderando o cache se estiver configurado, não responde o que foi perguntado, o questionamento é como fazer uma nova versão ser baixada após uma alteração