# Problemas pra exibir meu site no chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, layout-responsivo

Ola,
estou tendo problemas pra exibir meu site no Google Chrome. Eu edito os códigos principalmente no css, no mozila exibe na hora, mas no chrome ou demora muito (depois de atualizar umas 20 vezes) que funciona, ou nem atualiza de jeito nenhum.

O problema é só com o css.
Eu estou fazendo um tema para o wordpress, então eu uso o style.css

Eu chamo o style assim:

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Eu estou usando mais 3 páginas css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" >
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/grayscale.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/agency.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Foi necessário usa-las pra obter certos resultados que eu queria. Não sei se isso ta atrapalhando. Mas tive o mesmo problema num outro tema que eu estava desenvolvendo e só usei o style e o bootstrap.
Tudo isso pra fazer um site responsivo também.

Comment: Provavelmente seja porque o Chrome está armazenando cache de sua aplicação sem verificar alterações no arquivo.  Você pode tentar limpar o cache do navegador e atualizar a página ou utilizar as tags meta do HTML para desabilitar o cache permanentemente (aconselhável apenas enquanto desenvolvimento, para produção é melhor manter o cache).

Comment: Como eu faço isso?? Algumas coisas ainda estou aprendendo hehe!

Comment: Para limpar o cache do navegador: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?hl=pt-BR. Sobre as tags meta, pode ler mais sobre aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers

Comment: Deu certo Muito obrigado. Usei a tag. Você disse então que quando eu for colocar o site no ar eu preciso tirar as tags??

Comment: Exato, pois o cache beneficia no tempo de carregamento do seu site, deixando-o mais rápido.

Comment: como responder a pergunta nos comentários não é uma boa prática (o fiz apenas porque não tinha certeza se era esse mesmo o problema), transcrevi a solução como resposta. Se possível, marque-a como útil e sinalize o post como respondido.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como forçar carregamento de arquivos JS e CSS a cada nova versão publicada?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/84211/como-for%c3%a7ar-carregamento-de-arquivos-js-e-css-a-cada-nova-vers%c3%a3o-publicada)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apenas transcrevendo a solução que foi apresentada nos comentários.

O fato de não atualizar as alterações no navegador Chrome é o cache. Se não me engano, localmente, pelo menos, o Firefox mantém também versões dos arquivos em cache, mas os atualiza caso haja alguma alteração. Diferente do Chrome, que demora a atualizar os arquivos em cache naturalmente. Ou seja, uma vez que você carregou o arquivo CSS no Chrome, novas alterações não funcionarão enquanto o cache não atualizar.

São duas possíveis soluções:

1. Apagar o cache armazenado no navegador manualmente, seguindo os passos apresentados no [site oficial](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?hl=pt-BR), Limpeza de cache e cookies; ou
2. Utilizar as meta tags do HTML para controlar o cache da página, como pode ser visto [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers).

Resumidamente, basta adicionar a tag abaixo para que os navegadores não façam mais cache da página.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" />
```

> **Nota**: É aconselhável manter esta configuração apenas em ambiente de desenvolvimento. Uma vez que seu site está concluído e vá para o ambiente de produção, manter cache é algo extremamente saudável e recomendado, pois diminui o tempo de carregamento de sua página e reduz, também, tráfego do seu servidor.

Answer (score 0):

A única coisa que funcionou para mim foi inserir uma "hash" informando que existe uma nova versão do css para o chrome:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css?version=2">
```