# Meu arquivo css não altera formatação

Tags: php, html, css, formatação

Há alguns dias estou com esse problema. Coloco o arquivo css no documento home.php `<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet">` a formatação vai, mas depois quando vou incluir outras formatações no arquivo css.css não aparece alteração nenhuma. **Obs: É preciso criar outro arquivo css para as formatações irem tudo direito**, o que pode ser?

*Editor que uso: É o notepad+*

Comment: cache man, CTRL+f5....

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como forçar carregamento de arquivos JS e CSS a cada nova versão publicada?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/84211/como-for%c3%a7ar-carregamento-de-arquivos-js-e-css-a-cada-nova-vers%c3%a3o-publicada)

Comment: Já tentou incluir dentro de link: type="text/css" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para evitar o cache, você precisa passar uma variável com valor randômico no URL. Assim o navegador não achará o arquivo no cache e o solicitará ao servidor.

Se for na pagina PHP

```
$key = uniqid(md5(rand()));

href="css.css?key=<?php echo $key ?>"
```