# Usuário ver a versão atual do Jquery e CSS sem cache

Tags: jquery, css, cache

Sempre que atualizo o *CSS* e *JQUERY* de um site, preciso ficar pedindo para o cliente abrir o site em janela anônima. Pois o navegador dele salva os arquivos antigos e ele não consegue ver as alterações.

Qual a melhor forma de contornar isso?

Comment: Creio que se usa PHP esta resposta deve ser servir pro seu caso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117510/3635

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou fazer um resumo de todas as formas possíveis e te dar uma dica, utilize no final do import um numero randômico. 
Utilizo uma aplicação java e vou deixar um exemplo:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='${homePath}/script/jQuery/jquery-ui.js?v=${random.nextInt()}'></script>
```

Comment: O que é esse `${homePath}` e `${random.nextInt()}`? Acho randomico uma péssima ideia, pois você perde a principal vantagem, o CACHE http, o que torna o site mais lento de carregar para os usuários, ainda mais se estiver em uma internet móvel. O ideal para o autor ou pra qualquer um seria talvez algo "equivalente" a um checksum ou adaptar esta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117510/3635 para esse sistema de template que você aplicou.

Comment: A ideia de usar o numero randômico é evitar o "CACHE" como o autor da pergunta quer, se vai atrasar ou não no carregamento da página acho que a consequência é dele. Acho que a pergunta foi clara o suficiente

Comment: Exatamente o que o link que lhe indiquei **vai fazer**, ele também evita o cache, mas evita quando necessário, "quando ocorre atualizações" de verdade no .css ou .js.

Comment: A entendi, é que no momento estou sem poder olhar sua recomendação mais verei em breve, obrigado pela dica @GuilhermeNascimentoP.