# .HTACCESS dúvidas(especial mod_expires)

Tags: htaccess

Gostaria de entender melhor como funciona esse módulo, em especial deixo como exemplo o que está na pasta Raiz de um dos sites que manejo:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On 
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

- a parte `ExpiresDefault` define a expiração default de todos os itens(gif,
  png, css, js..) ?
- Então no meu.htaccess eu estou sobrescrevendo o valor default que foi
  definido anteriormente(quando defino expirar para png, jpeg.. especificamente) ?
- Se eu inicio o módulo mod_expires .htaccess em uma subpasta, mesmo
  vazio, ele sobrescreve o que foi escrito no módulo do .htaccess que
  fica na pasta raiz?
- É verdade que se eu usar parametros na URL, eu estarei forçando a cachear
  novamente, por exemplo, isso: `index.html`, ser diferente disso
  `index.html?1234`?

Answer (score 1):

> a parte ExpiresDefault define a expiração default de todos os itens(gif, png, css, js..) ?

- Não só dos gif, jpeg, png, mas de qualquer página acessada, até mesmo as dinâmicas. No entanto você pode usar `<FilesMatch>` pra filtrar os arquivos que deseja que recebam o `ExpiresDefault`, veja este exemplo:

  ```apacheconf
  #Qualquer página terá um cache de 1 mês
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

  #Arquivos que tem extensão como .gif, .jpg, .jpeg e .png terão um cache de 1 ano
  #Sobrescreve o primeiro
  <FilesMatch "\.(?i:gif|jpe?g|png)$">
      ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
  </FilesMatch>
  ```

> Então no meu .htaccess eu estou sobrescrevendo o valor default que foi definido anteriormente(quando defino expirar para png, jpeg.. especificamente) ?

- Sim, `ExpiresByType` sobreescreve pra página que usa o mimetype especificado.

> Se eu inicio o módulo mod_expires .htaccess em uma subpasta, mesmo vazio, ele sobrescreve o que foi escrito no módulo do .htaccess que fica na pasta raiz?

- Sim, os .htaccess de sub-pastas *"sobrescrevem"* os parâmetros e flags das pastas de nível superior.

> É verdade que se eu usar parâmetros na URL, eu estarei forçando a cachear novamente, por exemplo, isso: index.html, ser diferente disso index.html?1234?

- É verdade sim, pois pros navegadores `index.html` é diferente de `index.html?1234`, pois tudo que vem depois `?` é um parâmetro GET e significa que você esta buscando algo supostamente diferente, o navegador não tem como saber se `index.html` é uma página estática ou dinâmica, sendo que geralmente usamos `?` pra definir que estamos buscando algo dinâmico. É muito comum usar o `?` pra prevenir cache de `.js` e `.css`.

  Veja esta resposta: [Para que serve e quando usar versão em arquivos .js e .css?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/41157/3635)

  Note que alguns servidores *proxy* não interpretam `?` e por isto em alguns casos o cache não é ignorado.