# problema ao atualizar o css do meu site

Tags: css, navegador-de-internet

Bom tenho um problema que acho que afeta várias pessoas, e provavelmente alguém já passou por isso e resolver o problema.

Sempre que atualizo meu site, com um menu novo ou qualquer alteração no css, muitos usuários continuam com o css antigo no cache do navegador. Tem alguma forma de sempre que eu alterar o css o navegador do usuário atualizar ele, sem a necessidade de limpar o histórico do novedor?

Comment: Relacionada: [Para que serve e quando usar versão em arquivos .js e .css?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41153/4808).

Comment: Leia sobre este plugin: http://cssrefresh.frebsite.nl/ é muito bom.